# How to multiply two dimensional array by factor

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have two dimensional array

```
private static int [][] n = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
```

And I have

```
int m = 3;
```

How can I multiply each element in my two dimensional array by 3?
So that the output would be like this:

```
{{3, 6, 9, 12},{15, 18, 21, 24}}
```

Also, if I had a matrix like

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
{6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 
{11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, 
{16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, 
{21, 22, 23, 24, 25}},
```

How would I print the diagonal elements?

```
{1,7,13,19,25} and {5,9,12,17,20}
```

I'd like to know algorithm, because for multiplying dimensional array I used

```
private static int[] n = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

private static int[] multiply(int[] n, int m) {

    int array[] = new int[n.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        array[i] = n[i] * m;
    }
    return array;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate both dimensions:

```
private static int[][] multiply(int[][] n, int m) {
    int array[][] = new int[n.length][];
    for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        array[i] = new int[n[i].length];
        for (int j = 0; j < n[i].length; j++) {
            array[i][j] = n[i][j] * m;
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: It gives me an error in return(found int[], required int[][])

Comment: @MichaelKors yeah, I botched the variable definition, mea culpa. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You need 2 for loops for this

```
int [][] n = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}};
for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        n[i][j]*=3;
```

Here we are accessing the array row wise.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers didn't show you how to print diagonal elements, here it is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
    System.out.println(n[i][i]);
```

because diagonal elements have equal first and second indices: `[i][i]`

Comment: The reverse diagonal elements: System.out.println(n[i][n.length-1-i]);

Answer (score 1):

For the first task you can use a simple loop:

```
int m = 3;
for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n[i].length; j++){
        n[i][j] *= m;
    }
}
```

For the second one it's important to observe that elements in diagonal from `left-up to right-down` have the same index row and column. And diagonal from `left-down to right-up` you just need to reverse one either rows or columns. For example reversing rows, instead of starting with 0 you start with `row.length - 1`

```
 | 0  1  2  3  4
------------------
0| 1           5
1|    7     9
2|      13
3|   17     19    
4|21           25
```

So in order to get the diagonals you just have to do a loop:

```
int[] d1 = new int[array.length];

int[] d2 = new int[array.length];

for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    d1[i] = array[i][i];
    d2[i] = array[array.length-1-i][i];
}
```

You just only assure that both rows and columns have the same length, otherwise it could throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.